# Elementary OS Blocks Shift + Alt in Blender unlike other Linux Distros

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts

I have had trouble using Blender 2.81 due to the way Elementary OS keyboard shortcuts interact with the software.

The Set key combo for Selecting multiple edgeloops is Shift + Alt + Click. This works in Windows 10, MacOSX, and other Linux Distros.

I have confirmed on Blender's [stack exchange](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/122333/selecting-multiple-edge-loops-in-blender-2-8) others are having this issue.

Is there a way to modify how the system-wide shortcuts interact with programs?

Answer (score 1):

Go to `System Settings > Keyboard > Layout` and change "Switch Layout" to any other option besides Alt+Shift.